# Entity Framework Core Code First Update-Database does nothing

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Im trying to use Entity Framework Core with a Code First approach.

So far I have developed some models and my context. I have then added the EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to work with migrations. I have defined my ConnectionString property in the appsettings like follows:

```
"Data": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDb;User Id=user;Password=pass; Pooling=true; Max Pool Size=200; Min Pool Size=5"
}
```

(The user and password are correct btw)

In my DbContext then I have done the following:

```
public MyContext()
{
    Database.EnsureCreated();
}

// ...

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"];
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

When I run the `Add-Migration InitialDatabase` it works fine, it creates my migration with its tables. And then when I launch the App, because of the `Database.EnsureCreated()` in `MyContext` it creates the database for me and it works fine.

**The problem is** I would like to control my migrations. So I would like to not rely on the `EnsureCreated`. The thing is when I execute `Update-Database` the command apparentely works (it doesnt show any error) but it does not create my database. I think I am missing a way to tell `Update-Database` where is my connection string. I know you can pass a parameter to it but I've seen people using it without parameters. How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used EF-core, but for standard EF I use "update-database -project <projectname> -startupproject <projectname> -connectionstringname <connectionstringname>".  Where there can be multiple connection strings in the app/web.config.

Comment: Is database already exist? If Update-Database could not find the connection string, it would throw error. It would be no-op only in the case when the database is already present and there is nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable first using the VS Package Manager and this command:

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Debug'
```

then run:

```
Update-Database
```

If have configured the connection string in appsettings.debug.json, then it should create and initialize the database using your migration.